# Three.js - How to select light / camera

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, typescript

Question,

In [this](http://threejs.org/editor/) editor, it is possible to select a light or camera by clicking on it.
I know how to get this working for meshes (`raycaster.intersectObjects(objects)`), but since lights and camera's do not have meshes, how would I go about selecting such objects on click?

My thoughs were to implement some kind of box around it (say, a "picker") that is able to be hit by the raycaster by means of an invisible mesh?

Any thoughts or references on this?
Thank!

*NOTE: Answer written in TypeScript is preferred, but JavaScript is fine too!*

Comment: Probably mrdoob or West Langley can shed some... ahem, light on this. My guess is that you can actually see an object interacting with the light source. You could try to attach the light on a box geometry and give the material an opacity of 0 so it will have a hitbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely go with the invisible mesh solution.
Simply set the `visible` property of your material to `false` and that will do the trick.

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/Material